# Prendre un air mort d'amour

Tags: sens, expressions

*Les embrouilles de Calma* de Barry Jonsberg :

> -- Je vous aime, mademoiselle Plait ! ai-je crié. Je suis tombée amoureuse de vous.
>
> Ça l'a stoppé net. Moi aussi, d'ailleurs. (...) Le Pitbull (*) s'est
> retournée et m'a contemplée avec attention. Je me suis efforcée de
> **prendre un air mort d'amour**, mais je crois que j'ai échoué.

(*) Pitbull est le surnom de mademoiselle Plait.

Le contexte : Kiffo, le meilleur ami de Calma, la narratrice, est entré dans la maison du Pitbull, et Calma fait tout son possible pour empêcher Mlle Plait de rentrer chez elle.

Il est possible de dire *prendre un air grave* ou *prendre un air offensé*, mais la tournure *prendre un air mort d'amour* me surprend parce que Calma pourrait être "morte d'amour", mais son apparence non. Par contre, il est possible d'*avoir l'air morte d'amour*. Je n'ai pas trouvé d'exemple contenant *prendre un air mort d'amour* sur Internet. D'après vous, cette tournure est-elle acceptable ?

Comment: C'est l'air qui est mort d'amour, au masculin. comme: un air plein de gentillesse.

Comment: @Lambie Ce n'est pas l'air qui aime, c'est la personne.

Comment: @LPH Il avait l'air plein de sagesse. Il meurt d'amour pour elle, mais il n'en a pas l'air.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, eh bien, c'est la personne qu'on considère pleine de sagesse, pas son air (l'air de quelqu'un qui est plein de sagesse).

Comment: @LPH Non, *Elle est pleine de sagesse.* n'est pas: *Elle a l'air plein de sagesse*.

Comment: @Lambie La définition du dictionnaire dit « en parlant d'un organisme du règne animal ou végétal » ; il y a une erreur dans l'orthographe (morte d'amour), si on n'a pas affaire à ces questions de genres bizarres qui ne sont ni masculin ni féminins (dans ce dernier cas comment savoir quelle orthographe convient ?).

Comment: @LPH Sorry, I'm out. L'ouvrier qui l'a fondue en est **mort de joie**… Madame Bovary. https://www.ibibliotheque.fr/madame-bovary-gustave-flaubert-fla_bovary/lecture-integrale/page148

Comment: @Lambie Après *avoir l'air* quand il a le sens de *sembler*, l'accord se fait avec le sujet (*elle à l'air fatiguée*, *elles ont l'air petites*), après *prendre un air*, l'accord se fait toujours au masculin singulier puisque c'est l'air qui est qualifié.

Comment: https://www.gymglish.com/fr/frantastique-orthographe/regles-orthographe/elle-a-lair-ravie-ou-ravi#:~:text=Elle%20a%20l'air%20fatigu%C3%A9,on%20accorde%20avec%20l'air. Remarque : dans la plupart des cas, les deux sont possibles.Elle a l’air fatigué(e) : elle semble fatiguée on accorde avec le sujet ; elle a la mine fatiguée on accorde avec l'air.

Comment: @Lambie C'est exactement ce que j'ai écrit.

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est pas une combinaison habituelle ; sont couramment utilisées les suivantes.

- mort de peur/terreur/jalousie/faim/soif/froid/fatigue/sommeil/rire/…

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mort)) **II.** − Emploi adj.
> **A.** − [En parlant d'un organisme du règne animal ou végétal]
> **2.** Qui semble, sous certains aspects, avoir perdu la vie.
> **b)** Qui est privé pour des raisons intérieures ou extérieures (la fatigue, la maladie, la peur, etc.) d'une partie importante de ses moyens; fam. être à bout de forces.
> − [Le compl. de cause est exprimé] *Être mort de faim, de fatigue, de peur, de soif*
> ♦  Si elle m'avait poursuivi, je serais mort de terreur (Maupass., Contes et nouv.,t. 2, Peur, 1884, p. 963).
> ♦ Une existence de bête de somme menée à coups de fouet, morte de sommeil (Zola, Terre,1887, p. 142).

Cependant, des combinaisons comme « mort de joie » ne sont pas idiomatiques, ou du moins ne le sont plus ([mort de joie](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mort%20de%20joie%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)). On ne peut pas dire qu'on soit libre de faire des combinaisons. Il est à  noter que le substantif qui peut être combiné dénote  un état qui  du point de vue physique/moral/psychique est désagréable ; il existe même un point de vue selon lequel le rire à l'excès est désagréable—et « mort de » signifie toujours « *excès de … au point d'en souffrir beaucoup* ». On voit difficilement comment quelqu'un pourrait concevoir que son amour est excessif et souffrir beaucoup de cet excès. C'est vraiment une combinaison étrange, qui, personnellement ne me viendrait pas à l'esprit.

Le terme habituel dans ce contexte, au lieu de « mort d'amour » est « fou d'amour ».

Comment: Il existe une chose qui s'appelle l'écriture. On ne trouve pas "tout" déjà écrit. "mort de joie" n'est pas idiomatique? Seulement, "mort de peur"?

Comment: @Lambie Ce qui fait perdre la vie, ce qui handicape (dictionnaire) ne peut pas être la joie.

Comment: Si on peut se trouver "mort d'amour", on peut bien en avoir l'air d'être mort d'amour.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne pense pas que « mort d'amour » soit une combinaison qui préserve l'esprit de la grande majorité de celles qu'on trouve dans la bien parler, lesquelles, de plus, correspondent  à la définition du dictionnaire.

Comment: C’est de quoi Pierre Benoit devait donner un dernier exemple, un exemple plus tragique et nous savons qu’il est mort d’amour. https://www.academie-francaise.fr/discours-de-reception-de-jean-paulhan

Comment: @Lambie Il existe une différence subtile dans le cas d'utilisation que vous mentionnez ; l'usage n'est plus figuré mais littéral, la mort a résulté soit d'un dépérissement soit d'un suicide ou autre cause violente. Je ne crois pas qu'il s'agisse de l'usage figuré.

Comment: Si tu meurs d'amour tu es bien dans la métaphore. Aucun doute.

Comment: @Lambie Non, il s'agit de « mort d'amour » exactement comme « mort de la tuberculose », l'amour l' a trucidé.

Comment: LPH, merci beaucoup. Laissez tomber, ça tourne en ronde... Et puis, le but n'est pas de comprendre...

Comment: MDR.............

Comment: LPH ou @jlliagre Mais est-il possible de dire _prendre un air mort de rire_ ou _prendre un air fou d'amour_ ? Je pense que non. La question est surtout si un air pourrait être _mort de rire_ ou _fou d'amour_ ou c'est la personne qui a l'air _folle d'amour_.

Comment: @Oreste  Prendre un air de ci ou de ça c'est essentiellement faire semblant, ce qui revient à dire faire en sorte de donner l'apparence d'un sentiment ou d'une attitude sans que ce sentiment ou cette attidude soit vrai. Je l'ai déjà  dit dans un commentaire ci-dessus,  prendre un air fou d'amour  c'est prendre l'air **de quelqu'un qui est** fou d'amour, ce qui dit  que la personne serait folle d'amour, pas l'air. Qu'est-ce que l'air ? C'est un ensemble de  caractéristiques du comportement ; par exemple, dans ce cas, l'une de ces caractéristiques peut très bien être des  ; (1/2)

Comment: @Oreste yeux langoureux ;  que sont des yeux langoureux ? D'après le dictionnaire ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/langoureux)) ce sont des yeux qui « _**traduisent** l'abandon, la langueur d'une passion amoureuse_ » ; l'organe, la représentation que l'on en a, n'est qu'un instrument qui trahit le sentiment ; le sentiment, lui, se trouve strictement dans le cerveau, plus précisément, dans ce que l'on a convenu d'appeler l'âme, ce qui dépend de certaines cellules de la matière grise, mais qui n'est toujours pas cette matière. (What is mind? No matter! What is matter? Never mind!). (2/2)

Comment: Rien ne s'y oppose grammaticalement. Je ne vois pas non plus ce qui interdirait de simuler un air ou un autre mais je comprends que *prendre un air mort de rire* puisse questionner.

Comment: @jlliagre La grammaire sert la sémantique ; on peut écrire « la regardait avec des yeux amoureux », mais la grammaire exige alors que l'on change le sens de « amoureux » : ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amoureux))  [Avec des subst. exprimant un aspect phys. ou moral d'une pers. ou de son comportement] Qui est caractéristique d'une personne amoureuse  (ex. …mains amoureuses…). Même un bon acteur a peut-être un problème pour  rire à s'en tordre le ventre, néanmoins, il y parvient sans ressentir le rire ;  l'air ne ressent pas le rire, et à plus forte raison il ne peut pas en mourrir.

Comment: @LPH L'air ne ressent rien, *air* signifie ici *aspect*, *apparence*.

Comment: *Instantanément, l’ironie disparut de son visage qui **prit un air mort** ; son regard aigu exprimait toute la misère humaine.* D. H. Lawrence, *L'étalon*.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est bien ce que j'essaie d'expliquer au PO.

Comment: @LPH Mon commentaire commençant par *Rien ne s'y oppose* était ma réponse à la question posée par Oreste. Tu y as réagi à en semblant à priori ne pas être d'accord avec moi si j'ai bien compris ce que tu veux dire.

Comment: @jlliagre Non, du point de vue strict de la grammaire, je suis d'accord, il n'y a rien à dire.

Comment: LPH, _Prendre un air de ci ou de ça c'est essentiellement faire semblant_ ... _Je l'ai déjà dit dans un **commentaire ci-dessus**, prendre un air fou d'amour c'est prendre l'air de quelqu'un qui est fou d'amour_ D'abord, il est possible de se noyer dans vos discussions avec certains membres, si ce n'est pas mentionné dans votre réponse. Puis, j'ai relu vos commentaires antérieurs, et je ne trouve toujours pas cette remarque. Peu importe.

Comment: @jlliagre si _prendre un air X_ signifie _faire semblant_, comme l'a écrit LPH, alors oui _prendre un air mort d'amour_ est acceptable. Ce qui me gênait, c'est que, pour moi, X qualifiait _air_ et non la personne qui affiche cet air.

Comment: @Oreste *Prendre un air X* signifie que c'est l'air qui est qualifié d'où l'accord obligatoire au masculin singulier. La signification est bien que la personne qui prend ici cet air se donne l'apparence d'être quelqu'un "mort d'amour".

Comment: @Oreste Je fais référence à ce commentaire-ci :  “ (l'air de quelqu'un qui est plein de sagesse) » ; on le trouve sous votre question. Il est vrai que c'est légèrement différent, mais le principe est le même. Voir la remarque suivante du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/air) (entrée « air »), répétée ci-dessous pour plus de facilité de consultation. (1/2)

Comment: @Oreste Rem. Ce subst. (hormis les cas d'ell.) ne s'emploie que dans certaines conditions syntaxiques : il est obligatoirement suivi d'un adj., d'un subst. en fonction adjective, d'un compl. déterminatif, d'une prop. relative, ou, plus rarement, précédé d'un poss. ou d'un dém. **Il sert à attribuer à une personne une certaine apparence, une manière d'être précisée par l'adj. ou le syntagme équivalent**. Il a l'air bête signifie « il est apparemment bête ». (2/2)

Answer (score 1):

Ce qu'il est réellement important de comprendre ici est que le style utilisé ici participe beaucoup plus de la license artistique que de la rigueur grammaticale.